# improving bigint write to disk performance

Tags: distributed, bigint, chapel, parallelism-amdahl

I am working with really large `bigint` numbers and I need to write them to disk and read them back later because they won't all fit in memory at a time.

The current Chapel implementation first converts the `bigint` to a `string` and then writes that `string` to disk[1]. This is taking a really long time for large integers.

```
var outputFile = open("outputPath", iomode.cwr);
var writer = outputFile.writer();
writer.write(reallyLargeBigint);
writer.close();
outputFile.close();
```

Is there any way to use GMP's `mpz_out_raw()`/`mpz_inp_raw()`[2] or `mpz_export()`/`mpz_import()`[3] or another similar way to dump the `bigint`'s bytes to disk directly without converting to string beforehand and then read the bytes back into a `bigint` object?

Would that also work for a `bigint` array?

How could such functionality be added to Chapel's standard library in case it's not possible in the current state?

[1] https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/blob/master/modules/standard/BigInteger.chpl#L346

[2] https://gmplib.org/manual/I_002fO-of-Integers.html

[3] https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export.html

Comment: As you may have noticed, Chapel's `BigInteger` library is just a thin wrapper around `GMP`. You can still use the the `GMP` functions directly, and access the GMP type `mpz_t` via the `.mpz` field, so using `mpz_{in,out}_raw()` and `mpz_{import, export}()` should work.

Comment: A GitHub issue would be a better place for requesting to add this feature to the `BigInteger` module. If you're able to get the proposed raw or export approaches to work, it is probably worth contributing to the project as a pull request.

Comment: I'd love to contribute and integrate @David Iten's answer into Chapel directly. I'll look into this and make a pull request if can manage it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions you mentioned aren't directly available in any Chapel modules, but you can write [`extern` procs and `extern` types](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/technotes/extern.html#support-for-extern-declarations) to access the `GMP` functions directly.

First we need to be able to work with C files, so declare some procedures and types for them:

```
extern type FILE;
extern type FILEptr = c_ptr(FILE);
extern proc fopen(filename: c_string, mode: c_string): FILEptr;
extern proc fclose(fp: FILEptr);
```

Then we can declare the GMP functions we need:

```
extern proc mpz_out_raw(stream: FILEptr, const op: mpz_t): size_t;
extern proc mpz_inp_raw(ref rop: mpz_t, stream: FILEptr): size_t;
```

Now we can use them to write a `bigint` value:

```
use BigInteger;
var res: bigint;
res.fac(100); // Compute 100!

writeln("Writing the number: ", res);

var f = fopen("gmp_outfile", "w");
mpz_out_raw(f, res.mpz);
fclose(f);
```

And read it back in from the file:

```
var readIt: bigint;

f = fopen("gmp_outfile", "r");
mpz_inp_raw(readIt.mpz, f);
fclose(f);

writeln("Read the number:", readIt);
```

For arrays of `bigint` values just loop over them to write or read them:

```
// initialize the array
var A: [1..10] bigint;
for i in 1..10 do
  A[i].fac(i);

// write the array to a file
f = fopen("gmp_outfile", "w");
for i in 1..10 do
  mpz_out_raw(f, A[i].mpz);
fclose(f);

// read the array back in from the file
var B: [1..10] bigint;
f = fopen("gmp_outfile", "r");
for i in 1..10 do
  mpz_inp_raw(B[i].mpz, f);
fclose(f);
```

Comment: `COMPUTE BigInt number: 14.0 [us]`
`fileIO  BigInt   took: 4359.0 [us] / 158-digits`
( [TIME]-domain costs explode 2+ orders of magnitude to "save" a bit in [SPACE]-domain ) Facts matter more than the below expressed hate >>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/47780580
`fileIO  BigInt   took: 115872.0 [us] / 158-Mdigits`

Comment: @David Iten Thank you for your great answer. This worked for me!

Answer (score -5):

**Prologue:**
A **`size`** of data is a static attribute, but the flow is always our worst enemy ever.

> "*Could such functionality be added to Chapel's standard library?*"

With a current price of adding a few more units, tens or even many hundreds of `[TB]`-s of RAM-capacity, the problem is IMHO **never to be solved by any extension of the language** in the above sketched direction.

---

Why never? Because of the exploding costs:

If one spends just a few moments with facts, the following latency-map appears on a blank sheet of paper. While respective numbers may vary a bit, the message is in the orders of magnitude and in the dependency-chain of the thought process:

```
            ________________________________________________________________________________________
           /                                                                                       /
          /                   ________________________________________________________            / 
         /                   /                                                       /           /  
        /                   /          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx          /           /   
       /                   /          /                /                /          /           /    
      /                   / SOMEWHAT /   PRETTY       /  PROHIBITIVELY /          /           /     
     /  CHEAPEST         /  CHEAP   /    EXPENSIVE   /   EXPENSIVE    /          /           /      
    /   EVER            /   ZONE   /     ZONE       /    ZONE        /          /           /       
   /___________________/. . . . . / _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _/ ! ! ! ! ! ! ! !/          /           /_______________________
             /        /          /                /                /          /           /          /            /
   in-CACHE / in-RAM / CONVERT  / STORE          / RE-READ        / CONVERT  / in-RAM    / in-CACHE / in-CPU-uop /
      ~ + 5 [ns]     |          |                |                |          |           |          |            |
        + 5 [ns]     |          |                |                |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                |                |          |           |          |            |
            | ~ +300 [ns/kB]    |                |                |          |           |          |            |
            |   +300 [ns/kB]    |                |                |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                |                |          |           |          |            |
            |        |+VOLUME   [   GB]          |                |          |           |          |            |
            |        | x 100.000[ns/GB]          |                |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                |                |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          |+1              |                |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          | x    15.000.000[ns]             |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          |+VOLUME         [   GB]          |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          | x 3.580.000.000[ns/GB]          |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                |                |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                |+1 FIND         |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                | x    15.000.000[ns]       |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                |+1 DATA         |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                | x    15.000.000[ns]       |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                |+VOLUME         [   GB]    |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                | x 3.580.000.000[ns/GB]    |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                |                |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                |                |+VOLUME   [   GB]     |          |            |
            |        |          |                |                | x 100.000[ns/GB]     |          |            |
            |        |          |                |                |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                |                |          |    ~ +300 [ns/kB]    |            |
            |        |          |                |                |          |      +300 [ns/kB]    |            |
            |        |          |                |                |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                |                |          |           |    ~ + 5 [ns]         |
            |        |          |                |                |          |           |      + 5 [ns]         |
            |        |          |                |                |          |           |          |            |
            |        |          |                |                |          |           |          |    ~ + 0.3 [ns/uop]
            |        |          |                |                |          |           |          |      + 2.0 [ns/uop]
```

---

Last but not least, just [calculate such step's effects on `<< 1.0` speedup](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)

Given the original processing took **`XYZ [ns]`**,
the "modified" processing will take:

```
                          XYZ [ns]                  : the PURPOSE
+ ( VOL [GB] *    300.000.000 [ns/GB] )             :            + MEM/CONVERT   
+ ( VOL [GB] *        100.000 [ns/GB] )             :            + CPU/CONVERT
+                  15.000.000 [ns]                  :            + fileIO SEEK
+ ( VOL [GB] *  3.580.000.000 [ns/GB] )             :            + fileIO STORE
+                  15.000.000 [ns]                  :            + fileIO SEEK / FAT
+                  15.000.000 [ns]                  :            + fileIO SEEK / DATA
+ ( VOL [GB] *  3.580.000.000 [ns/GB] )             :            + fileIO RE-READ
+ ( VOL [GB] *        100.000 [ns/GB] )             :            + CPU/CONVERT
+ ( VOL [GB] *    300.000.000 [ns/GB] )             :            + MEM/CONVERT   

_______________________________________________
                   45.000.XYZ [ns]
+               7.660.200.000 [ns/GB] * VOL [GB]
```

**so, the such adversely impacted performance [will get damaged](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)** ( as Amdahl's Law shows ):

```
             1
S = ------------------------------------------------------------  << 1.00
     1  + ( 45.000.XYZ [ns] + 7.660.200.000 [ns/GB] * VOL[GB] )
```

Comment: This post is not addressing the OP's concern.  The information is interesting, but not appropriate here.

Comment: Is it "*not addressing the concern*"? It does address it more than anything else. **Would you Brian ever spend $45.000.000 to receive but $300?**. In case you would dare to, your shareholders will be fair to call it a plain robbery.